# IF/THEN using IsEmpty

Tags: excel, vba

Probably doing something wrong here, so if I am please let me know!

What I'm trying to accomplish:

- Loop through the cells in Column C, if there is a 6 digit number in the cell, then I want a formula to be added to the same row in Column U that adds the values in Columns M,N,P and R. If there is not a 6 digit number in the cell of Column C, then leave the cell in Column U alone.

[image]

My attempt to translate this into VBA is below. Note, I've added the "This Cell Should Be Empty" string to visualize if this function is doing anything temporarily. I will want to delete that.

Any suggestions to accomplish my intention here?

```
Sub IsEmptyRange()

Dim myRange As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim myOutput As Range


Set myRange = Range("C1:C10")
Set myOutput = Range("U1:U10")

For Each cell In myRange.Cells
  
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then
   
    myOutput.Value = "This Cell Should Be Empty"
        
    ElseIf IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
    
    myOutput.FormulaR1C1 = "=RC13+RC14+RC16+RC18"
    End If
Next cell
  

End Sub
```

Comment: Put your cursor on `IsEmpty` and press F1 and read what it does.

Comment: If there is a formula in column `C` the cell will never be empty but may be blank. To test if a cell is blank (`Empty` or `=""` or `'`) you can do `If Len(CStr(cell.value)) = 0 Then`. The `CStr` additionally 'saves' you from error values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at using the `IsNumeric` function along with `Len` ...

```
Public Sub TestForSixDigitNumber()
    Dim strValue As String
    
    strValue = "123456"
    
    If IsNumeric(strValue) And Len(strValue) = 6 Then
        MsgBox "Is a 6 digit number", vbInformation, "Success"
    Else
        MsgBox "Is NOT a 6 digit number", vbCritical, "Error"
    End If
End Sub
```

A word of caution though, decimal places aren't factored in here.

Alternatively, you could bake it into your formula directly, something along the lines of (changing the reference to A1) ...

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1), LEN(A1) = 6), Add your values, leave it alone)
```

Adapt as you see fit.